# How to fix javascript calculation error of checked values on forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The form I have set up has radio buttons with different values. The average is calculated based on which value is checked and how many values are checked. It is then rounded to the nearest whole number.  If value 1 is selected then that should be -1 in the calculation. It works perfect for some records. However the weird issue is that on some records the average calculated can be different value compared to a similar record depending on the order of the values being selected for example

7,5,7,1,5,5,3 prints an average of 5

3,5,5,1,7,5,7, prints an average of 4

7+5+7-1+5+5+3 gives you 31/7 = 4.42857 which should be 4 but it prints the average as 5

3+5+5-1+7+5+7 gives you 31/7 = 4.42857 and that prints the right average which is 4

Below is my code for calculation in js. I am not sure how that would happen. I would really appreciate help and hope that i have provided enough information.

```
   for(i = 1; i <= activities_num; i++){

      var value_str = $(`input[name=${section}${i}]:checked`).val();

        if(value_str !== undefined) {
            var value = parseInt(value_str);
            if(value === 1) {
               value = -1;
            }
            if(value === 0 ) {
               counter = counter -1;
            }
            options_values_sum += value;
            counter ++;
        }
        console.log(i); 
    }
    var average = Math.round(options_values_sum / counter);
```

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces these results

Comment: Hi @pumpsdev, i try to reproduce your error. I did crete 7 checked radios with 7,5,7,1,5,5,3 values and it results in average=4.

Comment: I ried to reproduce the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/hpvl/q0kedzwj/10/ It looks if the error is not there. Try to output other stuff to the console, like options_values_sum and counter.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would affect anything, but that `counter = counter -1` line feels wierd to be followed by `counter ++`. I would make it `if(value !== 0){counter ++;}` and leave the other counter++ off. (also, `counter --;` is a thing too, I think)

Comment: Yeah, this is baffling. Is it somehow leaving off a number? I would do what Hans said and add more to your console log, specifically to verify the variables `value`, `counter`, and `options_values_sum` after each iteration

Comment: median, mean and average are all different...seems you do not want "average" here perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any problem, here is a cleaner way, don't use counter etc.

We now have access to techniques such as map and reduce.

```js
const getChk = (section) => document.querySelectorAll('section${section}     input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

const computeAverage = (section) => {
  let arr = Array.from(getChk());
  if (arr.length > 0) { 
    return Math.round(arr.map(chk => (parseInt(chk.value) === 1) ? -1 : parseInt(chk.value))
                         .reduce((a, v) => a + v) / arr.length);
  } 
  return 0;
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    let avg = computeAverage('#average');
    document.querySelector('#result').innerText = avg;    
  }
});
```

```html
<section id="average">
  <label>3</label><input type="checkbox" value="3">
  <label>7</label><input type="checkbox" value="7">
  <label>5</label><input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <label>5</label><input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <label>7</label><input type="checkbox" value="7">
  <label>1</label><input type="checkbox" value="1">
  <label>5</label><input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <label>7</label><input type="checkbox" value="7">
  <label>5</label><input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <label>5</label><input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <label>7</label><input type="checkbox" value="7">
  <label>3</label><input type="checkbox" value="3">
</section>

<div id="result"></div>

<p>7,5,7,1,5,5,3 prints an average of 4</p>

<p>3,5,5,1,7,5,7, prints an average of 4</p>
```